# How to query child in Firebase database and then delete node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database setup in Firebase:

[image: Firebase Screenshot]

I am trying to write a script that searches within media (in all users) and returns a match if any particular media url matches the url argument I pass through. And if a match is returned I would like to remove this media key/node. However, my script is just returning null. Any ideas?

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/');
const url = 'https://XXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/william/1478471907-me.jpg';

return ref.child('media').orderByChild('url').equalTo(url).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
});
```

Comment: `media` is not a child of `users`. it's a child of a child. i don't think you can skip the UUID

Comment: Thanks for your comment @imjared. Not sure what you mean by 'i don't think you can skip the UUID'? Do you think this is achievable?

Comment: To clarify, the child of `users` is `B4KW...` so you'd need to probably do `ref.child('B4KW.../media').orderByChild('url')`. i _think_ you're getting a `null` result because `ref.child('media')` is non-existent (i could be very wrong here)

Comment: Thanks Imjared, that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanks to Imjared's feedback I've found a solution - including a way to remove the node:

```
// reference the media, B4K... could be an variable to target the correct key
const ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/B4KWeemv78R2GP7Jqul2f70kVM73/media');

return ref.orderByChild('url').equalTo(url).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  // get the key of the respective image
  const key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];

  // delete image node from firebase
  ref.child(key).remove();

  return {
    success: 1,
    message: 'Image deleted.'
  };
}
```